# How come my Backbone.js snippet can't find a DOM model?

Tags: javascript, html, css, backbone.js

Take a look at this snippet below:

```
<script>
$(function(){

    var to_username = "alex";

    window.Persona = Backbone.Model.extend({

    }); 

    window.PersonaList = Backbone.Collection.extend({
        model:Persona,
        url:function(){
            return '/js/personas/approval/user?to_username=' + to_username;
        }
    }); 
    window.Personas = new PersonaList;

    window.CheckView = Backbone.View.extend({
        tagName:'div',
        template: _.template($("#checkbox_friends").html()),
        initialize: function(){
            this.model.bind('change', this.render, this);
        },
        render:function(){
            $(this.el).html(this.template({}));
            return this;
        }
    }); 

    window.AppView = Backbone.View.extend({
        el:$("#add_friend_holder"),
        coreTemplate: _.template($("#add_friend_templ").html()),
        initialize:function(){ 
            this.render();
            Personas.bind('reset', this.addAllBoxes, this);
            Personas.bind('all',this.render, this);
            Personas.fetch({
                success:function(){ 
                },
                error:function(){
                }
            });  
        },
        addOneBox:function(persona){
            var check_view = new CheckView({'model':persona});
            this.$("#friend_ticker").append(check_view.render().el); //DOESNT APPEND!!!
        },
        addAllBoxes:function(){
            Personas.each(this.addOneBox);
        },
        render:function(){
            this.el.html(this.coreTemplate({}));
        }
    });
    window.App = new AppView;
});

</script>

<div id="add_friend_holder"></div>

<style>
    #friend_ticker{
        padding:6px;
        border:1px solid #ccc;
        background:#fff;
        width:200px;
    }
</style>
<script type="text/template" id="add_friend_templ">
    <button class="btn danger">Add Friend</button>
    <div id="friend_ticker">

    </div>
</script>
<script type="text/template" id="checkbox_friends">
    <input type="checkbox">
    Print this
</script>
```

Everything works except for one line:

```
this.$("#friend_ticker").append(check_view.render().el);
```

If I `console.log(check_view.render().el)` ....it's all good.

Except, my script doesn't find this.$("#friend_ticker"), even though it's right there. I dont' see anything printed on the screen.

Comment: @RayToal Even if I remove it, it doesn't work.

Comment: Funny thing is..when I do console.log($("#friend_ticker")); in the script, it shows the data appended. When I do console.log($("#friend_ticker")); in the Chrome console, it shows <div id="friend_ticker"></div>  It's like...it's referring to TWO DIFFERENT dom elements

Comment: The script thinks that $("#friend_ticker") is still the one inside <script type="text/template">, and not the one that got "drawn".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could it be that you are rendering the view 2 times after fetch as you bind to two Collection events.

```
Personas.bind('reset', this.addAllBoxes, this);
Personas.bind('all',this.render, this);
```

The first call fills the view with subtemplates. The second then renders the parent empty again.

Answer (score 0):

ProTom is correct in that the view is being rendered twice. Perhaps you may want to bind to the collections "add" event instead of "all".

Here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vyuz9/) as an example where the view renders, I manually added an item to the list and bound the add event of the collection. In addition i commented out

```
   Personas.bind('all',this.render, this);
```

If you uncomment that line you will see that your render event gets fired twice and "erases" the div's content